The call to SetClipboardData after EmptyClipboard
Is call to SetClipboardData needed after the call to EmptyClipboard when the clipboard is opened using a nullptr argument? When clearing the clipboard content, can the call to SetClipboardData be omitted?
if (!OpenClipboard(nullptr)) {
    return false;
}
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, nullptr); // is this needed as-is
CloseClipboard();

The code is used to clear the clipboard content. No clipboard owner is needed. Is it safe to omit the SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, nullptr); call?

If you just want to clear the clipboard, it doesn't make sense to call SetClipboardData() to put a data item into the clipboard. Specifying a null handle for the item sets it up for delayed rendering.
So yes, omit the call to SetClipboardData() in this example.

The documentation is flat-out wrong and has been so for years. This Q&A is at least the second question asking for clarification.

@IInspectable fine. I removed that part of my answer
